# Efficient way to find folder directory within top 3 levels

Tags: vb.net, windows, path, filesystems

Simply put, I'm looking for a quicker way than windows search to find a folder within a specified string within a directory.

I have a `C:\Root`.

I know within the top 3 folder levels I will find a folder of name `Target`

i.e. `C:\Root\Sub1\Sub2\Target`

Is there a quick and efficient way to do this?
I will always be looking for a folder, and it will always start with some search string entered by the user.

In the end I want to make a form to enter the search string. This part I should be able to figure out on my own.

Comment: Do you have tried with some code you want to share? (see [ask])

Answer (score 0):

The System.IO.DirectoryInfo and EnumerateFiles objects and methods are very powerful in this regard.  For example, you could try something like this:

```
Public Sub SearchDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String, ByVal targetFileName As String)

    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory)
    For Each fi In di.EnumerateFiles(targetFileName, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Console.WriteLine(fi.Name)
    Next

End Sub
```

You may have to play with it to get it to work the way you want, as there may be issues related to directory permissions, etc.  This should get you off to a good start though.

Comment: If you're committed to the idea of only allowing for a search of 3 directories, you should explore the idea of designing a recursive search function using the System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles command.

Comment: That sounds like the road I will have to go down. I had taken a quick glance at the SearchDirectory, but only saw all or Top level, so I was hoping there was an easier way aside from recursion.